# Laravel facade Slug won't work for non English?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I want to create an URL string for non English stories from the story title

Ex: if the title is 
Laravel में आपका स्वागत है
URL will be /Laravel-में-आपका-स्वागत-है-ag16826

Laravel has a facade Slug. But it won't work for non English.

How i can do this?? any help or suggestion!!!
or any links where i can get help.

Comment: Have you checked this please do confirm and let us know

Comment: <?php function make_slug($string) { return preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', trim($string)); } $slug = make_slug("Laravel में आपका स्वागत है"); echo $slug; ?> Its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method might help you [URL SLUG](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sgmurphy/3098978/raw/12de48004832683d2dc44e179634a4e7a97f0dbf/url_slug.php) , i tried this but spelling mistakes are there

Try this first,

```
Route::get('/test',function(){
    return preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', trim('Laravel में आपका स्वागत है'));
});
```

Output

```
Laravel-में-आपका-स्वागत-है
```

Comment: Its not exactly what i wanted but I found out a little solution of that you can check here <?php
function make_slug($string) {
    return preg_replace('/s+/u', '-', trim($string));
}

$slug = make_slug("Laravel में आपका स्वागत है");
echo $slug;
?>

Comment: No i checked that it's returning the same string

Comment: yes actually  i forgot the '\' this one. Thank you.

Comment: If this resolved your problem please mark as resolved